# How to programmatically display version/build number of target in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

How can I programmatically get the value of the `target version`, like in the image below?

As seen in the Properties window of the target of my Xcode project. I want to display this in the splash screen of my app so I know which version the people are currently using?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

There are **2** Numbers!

The marketing release number is for the customers, called **version number**. It starts with *1.0* and goes up for major updates to *2.0*, *3.0*, for minor updates to *1.1*, *1.2* and for bug fixes to *1.0.1*, *1.0.2* . This number is oriented about releases and new features. It does not have to stop at 9, *1.11.23* is a reasonable version number.

The **build number** is mostly the *internal number of builds* that have been made until then. But some use other numbers like the branch number of the repository or its commit number. This number should be *unique* to distinguish the different builds, which only have minor incremental changes.

---

#### To get the **version** number:

Objective-C:

```
NSString * appVersionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Swift < 3.0:

```
let appVersionString: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
```

Swift 3.0+ (tested with 5.0):

```
let appVersionString: String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
```

#### To get the **build** number:

Objective-C:

```
NSString * appBuildString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Swift < 3.0:

```
let buildNumber: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

Swift 3.0+ (tested until 5.0):

```
let buildNumber: String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

#### If you want **both** in one:

First use the above lines and then the following one.

Objective-C:

```
NSString * versionBuildString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version: %@ (%@)", appVersionString, appBuildString];
```

Swift (tested until 5.0):

```
let versionAndBuildNumber: String = "\(appVersionString) (\(buildNumber))"
```

#### Notes:

The values in the main bundle are not always present, for example in a command line application there is no `CFBundleShortVersionString` or `CFBundleVersion`, so the methods will return `nil` and it will crash because in the code it makes a incorrect downcast.
But in normal Cocoa iOS and Mac apps these values are defined and will not be deleted.

This is tested with *Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)*. The build number is often written in parenthesis / braces. The build number is in hexadecimal or decimal.

[image: buildandversion]

---

In **Xcode** you can auto-increment the **build number** as a **decimal number** by placing the following in the `Run script` build phase in the project settings

```
#!/bin/bash    
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

For **hexadecimal** build number use this script

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber)) 
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1)) 
buildNumber=$(printf "%X" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

---

For `Xcode` do the following:

#### Step 1

[image: step1]

#### Step 2

[image: step2]

#### Step 3

[image: step3]

Comment: Just to add for the above example, "CFBundleVersion" is the Build=300, "CFBundleShortVersionString" is the Version=0.41. Viktor's answer should be the correct answer.

Comment: I had problems with hex numbers once. Apple states to use integers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364

Comment: Do you know if there are there any string constants for @"CFBundleShortVersionString" and @"CFBundleVersion" ?

Comment: Now that CI/CD systems are pretty common, you may want to point out the pitfalls of using build scripts to set version #'s with those.

Comment: Things have been renamed for Swift 3.0: it's `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "...")` now.

Comment: Warning.  The New Build System doesn't copy CFBundleVersion into the app's dictionary.  FYI.  Tested in Xcode 11.4.

Comment: @AlexZavatone, are you still seeing the same problems in XCode 12 with CFBundleVersion not being copied into the dictionary? In XCode 12.4 it's working for me, and with my app project I'm able to retrieve CFBundleShortVersionString successfully. XCode12 is the first version I'm using, so perhaps this is related to the change from CFBundleVersion to CFBundleShortVersionString?

Comment: @Rethunk, I'll have to check it out. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to change anything in your project or Xcode. Here's the Swift version for both separately:

```
let versionNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let buildNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

It's included in this repo, check it out:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: which answer? i dont see it

Comment: There's only one answer, it's in his second paragraph

Comment: Yeah, 1. Theres too much noise and not much signal in his answer. 2. This is swift, that is objective-c. 3. Thats from ios5 era

Comment: Things have been renamed for Swift 3.0: it's `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "...")` now.

Answer (score 6):

Here same code for **Swift 3**:

```
let versionNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let buildNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

Comment: `Bundle.main` had an empty `infoDictionary` for me; maybe because I'm doing it from within a framework, not an executable or app? `Bundle(for: MyClass.self)` contains the expected values.

Answer (score 4):

**Programmatically display version and build number - Swift 4.0**

```
let versionNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "1.0"

let buildNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "1.0"            

let versionAndBuildNumber = "Ver #\(versionNumber) ( Build #\(buildNumber) )"
```

Answer (score 4):

I made an extension for Bundle so it will be easy to use

```
extension Bundle {
    var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }

    var buildVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }

    var applicationName: String {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String ?? "ADKATech"
    }

    var applicationReleaseDate: String {
        return infoDictionary?["ApplicationReleaseDate"] as? String ?? Date().description
    }

    var applicationReleaseNumber: Int {
        return infoDictionary?["ApplicationReleaseNumber"] as? Int ?? 0
    }

    var releaseVersionNumberPretty: String {
        return "\(releaseVersionNumber ?? "1.0.0")"
    }

    var buildVersionNumberPretty: String {
        return "\(buildVersionNumber ?? "1")"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like

```
var appVersion: String {
  //versionNumber
  let versionNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "1.0"

  //buildNumber
  let buildNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "1.0"

  return "Version: #\(versionNumber) (#\(buildNumber))"
}
```

Then you can use anywhere when you declare Globally.

```
print(appVersion)
```

Output:

```
Version: #1.0 (#1.0.3)
```